# SheLo Asani Goy

Tags: tefilla, sources-mekorot, blessing

Who Created the bracha: SheLo AsaNi Goy?

I don't know which rabbi created it exactly and I would like to know who it was.

Comment: Why would you assume it's any different than the rest of the brachos recited every morning?

Comment: And similarly, in addition to what @Ploni said, why would you assume it was one, individual rabbi who enacted it?

Comment: Why would it matter who may have first suggested this to the Chachamim when they were setting up the sidur?

Answer (score 4):

Refer to this [beureihatefillah.com](http://www.beureihatefila.com/files/Sh_Lo_Asani_Goy-_Eved-_Isha.pdf) article. Elements of the formulation of this bracha are mentioned in *Menachot 43b* and *Tosefta Brachot ch. 6*. The wording of this bracha evolved.

I'm summarizing one of the main points from the article:

From Tal. Menachot - Rav Meir (some say it was Rav Yehuda) states that one should say שעשני ישראל - Who made me an Israelite. Tosefta suggests the negative version. See the bottom of p. 108 in that article where it explains that the version we see in the Talmud is just the result of later censorship.

Of notable interest is a version that uses the word נכרי instead of גוי as mentioned at the bottom of p. 109.